# associated models and validating

Tags: cakephp, associations, model-associations, cakephp-2.2

Every 3 people create 1 page in my app. So each `Page`, `hasMany` `User`.

I have defined some validation rules for checking users information. (like email, tel and zip code checker.) But each page (owners) needs just one email and telephone number. So email and tel are required just for first user. (Other users don't have to fill them. And first user HAVE TO do it.)

So, I have to remove some validation rules after I validate first user data. But I don't know how to do it with `saveAll` (`saveAssociated`) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip validation for a particular field by adding

`unset($this->User->validate['field_name']);`

before the `validates()` & `save()` calls.

Comment: I know that, and I have used it a lot. But here we don't have `save` method. It's `saveAll`.

Comment: If you invalidate a field, it doesn't matter which method you call to save the data. That field will not be validated, because the validation rules(for that field) do not exist anymore. So this should also work for `saveAll`.

Comment: `saveAll`, validates and save all users data at once. So I can't unset validation rules after validating first user.

Comment: In that case you should validate the data before saving, and then use `$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate' => false));`

Answer (score 0):

I have to manage it by copying first user email and telephone number to other users (And set some variables to keep default email and tel) . Then, validate the request data. And then revert default values for 2 other users.

Any other suggestions are welcome.